# What is the legal definition of an "as of" date in the banking world?

Tags: banking, email

My `American Express` credit card account is being sold to `Barclaycard` because `JetBlue` was not able to "reach terms" with `American Express`.

JetBlue has been sending communications via email that this change will be smooth and will not require anything on my end. However, I do not wish my account to be transferred.

In the email communication, it is noted:

> You’ll automatically receive your new card* — there’s no need to
>   reapply.

and later on in the email:

> *Your account must remain open, in good standing and in eligible status as of March 18, 2016, to be transferred to Barclaycard.

I contacted American Express requesting them to close my account. They say the cannot because the transfer already started. But, `open`, `good standing`, and `eligible status` are card statuses that can change?

Also, the change is stated to take place `As Of March 18`. No time is stated;  how can that be understood in the legal area? As of start of March 18th? What time zone? Where?

Comment: Informational emails from X don't constitute a contract between you and someone else. You need to look at your actual contract (agreement). There may be some obscure consumer rights provision that is external to the contract in your jurisdiction, wherever that is. "As of March 18" means "on" (a date). It does not entail anything about hour or time zone.